# Spring Security doesn't recognize which logged in user

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, angular5

I add Spring Security to my Spring Boot application but after, authentication process server doesn't recognize the same user in next request. I use Angular 5 for UI and maybe this issue in UI side may be requested not include cookies. Help me, please understand why Spring Security doesn't recognize user with already logged in.

In web configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/user/login").permitAll();
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/rest/user/login")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .successHandler(logInSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(authFailureHandler)
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/rest/user/logout", "POST"))
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutHandler)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1);

    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Session manager is activated `.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1);`

And authentication complete successful my `UserDetailsService` implementation correctly return `User` object by login and password. But next request to this controller:

```
@GetMapping("/rest/list")
public RestList list() {
    ...
}
```

Redirect to :

```
@Component
public class UnauthorizedHandler implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authException.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I have the logged in checker:

```
@Component
public class LoggedInChecker {
    public User getLoggedInUser() {
        User user = null;

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication != null) {
            Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
            // principal can be "anonymousUser" (String)
            if (principal instanceof UserDetailsImpl) {
                UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) principal;
                user = userDetails.getUser();
            }
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

I use this checker in `UserService`

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private LoggedInChecker loggedInChecker;

    @Override
    public User getUserByUsername(String username) {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getPermissions(String username) {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        return nonNull(user) ? user.getRoles().stream().map(Role::getRole).collect(toList()) : Lists.newArrayList();
    }

    @Override
    public User getCurrentUser() {
        return loggedInChecker.getLoggedInUser();
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean isCurrentUserLoggedIn() {
        // This place must call but nothing happening
        return nonNull(loggedInChecker.getLoggedInUser());
    }
}
```

I thought Spring automatically call my `UserSevice` for check authorization. But how to specify `HttpSecurity` for save information about the session?

In Angular side I use `HttpClient`:

```
@Injectable()
export class CoreApi {
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/rest/';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public get(url: string = ''): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.getUrl(url));
  }
}
```

Maybe You know how to specify Spring Security for checking auth with `LoggedInChecker` or another way for this reslt, let me know. Thank You!

Comment: From your Angular app, when you send request, each time you are redirected on auth url and after successful authentication request redirect to the required url? Or your Spring app pass through request without redirection on auth address? From my experience, you should make some magic in Angular to be sure that it will send authentication cookie in each request.

Comment: Increase log level it might be helpful to find a cause of this. BTW: LoggedInChecker class, in my opinion, should have session scope.